# PHP variable not passing through to another function sometimes

Tags: php

Edit: Made more clearer

I have a problem with a variable disappearing between function calls

firstly I start here with $pid being an int taken from a JSON string

```
print "PID".$pid."\n";
$a['points'] = Algorithm::getpredictionForPlayer($pid);
```

I get the output 'PID12' which is how it should be

Next in the Algorithm::getpredictionForPlayer

```
static function getpredictionForPlayer($pid)
{

            print "PID2:  ".$pid."\n";
    $points =0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    print "algorithm: ".$pid."\n";
        $points += v4::predictPointsForPlayer($pid);
    }

    return intval($points/10);
}
```

Occasionally i get 'PID2: 12', but more often all that prints is 'PID2: ' 
Is there a reason the variable would disappear during this time?

Comment: Have you echoed out the $pid in each case with some date time stamp? Sometimes there, sometimes not means the getpredictionforplayer method should be getting it sometimes but not others, so the problem is outside.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce it, we have no idea...

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? When does the "error" comes? What error comes? What is `$pid` when an error occurs?

Comment: Do you always see it in the getpredictionForPlayer function? or the problem starts there? If so can you please provide the code that calls the function?

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if v4::predictPointsForPlayer() takes its argument as a reference and then changes the value of it.

Comment: If $pid does not pass through the function, is that happen 10 times in your loop or only one time? If it is the first case, use var_dump($pid); to know what it is pass through the function getpredictionForPlayer.

Comment: Please place the calls to `getpredictionForPlayer` in your code. More than likely `$pid` in some of your calls are blank.

Comment: I edited the question, to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: It wouldn't just disappear, it's more likely something is different between when it's displayed and when it's not. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? if you don't have a debugger, invest in one! But you can use var_dump just before the method call to debug it manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable in the global scope is $pid yet you are passing $player_id into the function

```
print "PID".$pid."\n";
$a['points'] = Algorithm::getpredictionForPlayer($player_id);
```

You've then got a parameter in your static method called $pid

```
static function getpredictionForPlayer($pid)
```

but this isn't the same as the variable in your global scope. In fact this will take the same value as the $player_id that you are passing in. If you want the $pid variable from your global scope to exist in the static method you should pass it in instead of $player_id.

btw, you should think about whether you really need a static method. Generally they make things hard to test and should be avoided if possible. Should you have a player object and call the method getPrediction() on that?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I just simplified it a little when I posted on here, it is correct right now.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$a['points'] = Algorithm::getpredictionForPlayer($player_id);
```

To this:

```
$a['points'] = Algorithm::getpredictionForPlayer($pid);
```